# function to subset data supplying subset argument as text string

Tags: r, function, subset, eval

```
 m <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
 l <- list(a=1:3, b='c')
 d <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=3:1)
```

I was wondering if it is possible to make a function that takes a base R object (matrix, vector, list or data.frame, ...) as well as a text that specifies the subset of the object.

```
f1 <- function(object, subset) {
    # object'subset' 
  }
```

For instance

```
f1(m, '[1,1]') #to evaluate m[1,1]
f1(l, '[[1]][2:3]') #l[[1]][2:3]
f1(d, '$a') #d$a
```

would give us (respectively):

```
[1] 1
[1] 2 3
[1] 1 2 3
```

I guess the function need somehow to glue the two arguments before evaluating. I guess one could make a kind of interpreter for each bit of the subset text and the (for the matrix example) do something like:

```
`[`(1,1)
```

This would possible but I thought there would be an easier more direct way (my 'glue' above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  f1<-function(object, subset){    
    return(eval(parse(text=paste0(substitute(object),subset)))) 
 }

> m=matrix(4,2,2)
> l=list(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))
> f1(m,'[1,1]')
[1] 4

> f1(l,'[[1]][1:2]')  
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Well one way to go is to use `eval(parse))` methodology, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(x, text){
  eval(parse(text = paste0(x, text)))
}

f1('d', '$a')
#[1] 1 2 3

f1('m', '[1,1]')
#[1] 1

f1('l', '[[1]][2:3]')
#[1] 2 3
```